# Restoring previous on Adobe Illustrator

Tags: file-management

A good friend of mine had been working on a file now since June 30, 2018. She accidentally started working over the file without realizing it and her history only goes back to a 100, and even going that far a good chunk of her work is gone. We tried reverting the file which did not go far back enough, and also tried reverting it with Windows file revert option but no luck. Is there any possibility to remove the new work she did over her old work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A file is a file: if your history only goes back so far that's as much as you can revert. The file itself doesn't store any history, it's all on Illustrator; as soon as you close the program the history is gone.

The only solution is to get a previously backed up version of the file (your friend does back up often, doesn't she?). There's no other magic solution.